# Flutter StreamBuilder to monitor for Firebase Auth state

Tags: flutter

When I have a logged user, my wrapper check for additional data and once find it will open the HomeScreen of my application.

However, the Stream Builder does not return the SignIn screen even if user successfully logout.

As I can see the Home page is built in a different tree (but how to build it in the main tree?), don't know if this should interfere.

Main code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(),
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthService>(
          create: (_) => AuthService(),
        ),
      ],
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: appColor,
            primaryColorLight: appColor,
            primaryColorDark: appColor,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'WhyBye',
          //todo: Queste righe saranno necessarie quando avremo anche la versione WEB
          // home: ResponsiveLayout(
          //     webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
          //     mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout()),
          //todo.

          initialRoute: '/wrapper',
          routes: {
            '/wrapper': (context) => const Wrapper(),
            '/signInScreen': (context) => const SignInScreen(),
            '/signUpScreen': (context) => const SignUpScreen(),
            '/registrationScreen': (context) => const RegistrationScreen(),
            '/homeScreen': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
            '/recoverPasswordScreen': (context) =>
                const RecoverPasswordScreen(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Wrapper code:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: authService.user,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final User? user = snapshot.data;
          //return user == null ? const SignInScreen() : const HomeScreen();
          if (user == null) {
            return const SignInScreen();
          } else {
            WidgetsBinding.instance
                ?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => asyncMethod(context));
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: appBarColor,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: appBarColor,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

void asyncMethod(BuildContext context) async {
  final FirebaseMethods _firebase = FirebaseMethods();
  bool isTrue = await _firebase.isRegistrationUserCompleted(_firebase.getUID());
  if (!isTrue) {
    Variables.isCustomUserPic = false;
    Variables.isSocialUserPic = false;
    await _firebase.loadDefaultUserPicUrl();
    //& qui devo andare alla registrazione utente.
    if (Variables.isSignUp) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RegistrationScreen()),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RegistrationScreen()),
      );
    }
    //Navigator.pop(context);
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
    );
    //Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

And my very simple Home Screen:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const IHome();
  }
}

class IHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const IHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('LogOut'),
          onPressed: () async {
            bool isTrue = await AuthMethods().signOut();
            if (isTrue) {
              //Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            //Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the widget tree when a user is logged in and the wrapper loads the Home Screen.

[image]

As you can see I need to check other data before to switch to Home Screen, it's a post-account data that I need.

However when a user is logged in I open the Home Page directly from the Wrapper, but the Logout is not recognised (I checked the logout works well).

Here the widget tree when the wrapper chose the SignIn screen (because the user is not logged in).

[image]

As I should understand I probably need to avoid to use Navigator to open HomeScreen, but I don't know how to do.

Many thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of reasons why you don't get rerouted when the `authStatechange`:

could be a major issue with how your `provider` and `state notifiers` are created and are being used.

I suggest you listen for `authStateChange` in your `Wrapper Widget` instead, here is a brief example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Your App Name',
      home: _getLandingPage()
  );
}

Widget _getLandingPage() {
  return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
         return MainPage();
      } else {
        return LoginPage();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

OR

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .userChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

You can find more info [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state)

Comment: This type of listner must be called on every screen? Probably in initState?

Comment: Preferably you just have to listen once within the `MaterialApp`, and the state of your app would be automatically updated whenever there is a change to the `authState` of a signedIn user.

Comment: Hi Tim, many thanks, I will try. Meanwhile I'm thinking about my code. I run SignIn screen from the Wrapper directly and when I push other screens from SignIn all of those receive the StreamBuilder events. At apposite I launch the HomeScreen from a different process (asyncMethod), may be this the reason why I lose connection with the StreamBuilder?
Finally, please if you can, should you update your code to understand how can I put StreamListerner inside MaterialApp? :-)

Comment: updated with a full example

Comment: Many thanks Tim, I will try as soon as possible

Comment: Hi Tim, your solution works as Firebase manual. However my registration process handles a lot of screens and StreamBuilder is not the correct handle at end.
I just done some manual routing, screen by screen, by using the Firebase Listener itself.